# Difference between "Actively refused connection" and "Did not properly respond after a period of time"

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

When ConnectAsync method of Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket class fails, I get 2 types of errors.

> "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

or

> "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Both the errors happens randomly, hence I can't figure out the difference between the two. What is the technical difference between these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The former usually means that the target machine is inaccessible (e.g. it's off, or your internet connection is down, etc.)
- The latter means the machine has been reached, but the TCP port is not open (usually it means that the server program is not running; there is no socket listening on it).

Note that if the target machine is running a firewall application that blocks this port, it's usually configured to pretend the machine is inaccessible (by silently dropping all connection requests) instead of actively refusing the connection.